# Is this sentence correct ?

Tags: grammaticality

An extraordinary supply of goods was available, but the warehouse did not have enough space to store it.

In this sentence warehouse is singular or plural? Shouldn't it be has or something else.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The word warehouse itself here is a singular word, but the reason we don't use "has" in the sentence is that:
1) "Has" is present simple tense while the sentence in written using past simple tense.
2) We already have "verb to do" in the sentence (to make it negative); therefore, when any change occurs when conjugating a verb, it will happen to "verb to do" not "the main verb."
Example:
1. The movie "didn't" make me excited at all.
2. He "does" not do any housework.

Focus on both the main verbs and verbs to do in both of the statements and you'll get your answer. :)

Comment: Please do not answer questions too basic for a site devoted to 'linguists ...'.